# Script for non-stop enabling/disabling "Is trigger" on collliders2d in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity, unityscript

I had asked before that I have a problem with too many colliders in one spot and that some upgrades of towers I have are buggy due to that.

It has come to my notice, that whenever I *enable* the "Is trigger" on a colliders in the upgrading spots, it fixes, but if I start the scene again it is broken **sometimes** untill I *disable* it again.

So what script should it be to atatch to those spots to activate/deactivate the is trigger toggle non-stop?

This is a video of me trying to explain my problem from previous threads I've made elsewhere.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPFAxoPrHzs&feature=youtu.be

Comment: You're describing a problem and asking how to implement a solution that might not be the best solution. Perhaps you can modify the question to describe the problem more, and ask for solutions to the problem? You'll likely get better results with that approach. It's not clear you know *why* setting 'Is Trigger' is working for you and if that's actually an acceptable solution to the problem. You'll need to be as descriptive as possible when defining your problem. Phrases like "buggy", "broken" don't adequately describe the situation.

Comment: This is my situation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPFAxoPrHzs&feature=youtu.be

I was given a few suggestions from other places, but with no better results (or I might have just gotten it wrong)

Comment: So you have two items, the monster and the tower "location circle". The monster is just there for show, and the location circle is what you click on to add a monster, and what you click on to upgrade the monster?

Comment: I click on the same spot again, which is now below a circle colliders (and that circle collider is on the monster itself because it uses that for range)

Comment: I don't understand, how many colliders do you have at the circle?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter how many colliders there are. Just use a [RaycastAll](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.RaycastAll.html) when you click the mouse, then iterate through the colliders looking for the game object you're interested in. A simple way to find the object you're looking for is to see if it has whatever your tower script is. Something like:

```
if(collider.gameObject.GetComponent<TowerScript>() != null)
     //activate the upgrade for that specific tower
```

Alternatively, you can put the tower in a different collision layer. Then use a mask on your raycast to only get objects in that layer.

Comment: The circle collider is what makes my towers have range. If there's those ugly things inside the circle collider the tower will shoot them. and I have already removed the drag feature and same :/

Comment: Both solutions stated by @Byte56 are the correct solutions unless you have a clear way to structure your interactions such that they don't overlap. For example, using a menu, or unified command system.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Exchange is asking to avoid this type of answers based on opinion, but as this question is about "how to fix a bug because of my implementation" and not the "how to do a particular thing", I could not answer it another way.

But avoid …

Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.

By monster I mean - tower(turret).

Well you have a problem because of your game design actually - why would you upgrade the monster if you would like to drag him? When you start dragging you click on the monster, thus it upgrades.

The solution would be to make that monsters that have to be upgraded cannot be dragged before they actually are upgraded, so player would have to click twice in order to upgrade and then again in order to drag the monster. Simple implementation is for your monsters to have XP and make them glowing when they can be upgraded. Otherwise if you have gold - it is not clever solution to make your player use his gold in order to drag the monster - so you would have ask with the UI for the action he wants to do or you would have to bind another key for dragging the tower.

As for the solution to actually get the script if you have multiple scripts for different kind of turrets. You can ray-cast from the camera to that monster onto turret layer and use `hit.GetComponent<Turret>().UpgradeTurret();` - it is possible to do for any script that will be upgraded using Inheritance and Polymorphism. For example if you have PoisonTurret and IceTurret they both will Inherit from Turret class, thus they both will have implementation of UpgradeTurret();. Also I guess every turret has it's own way of upgrading itself, thus it would be good to make Turret class `abstract`, add UpgradeTurret as abstract method, then override it in every child class. Or you could make an Interface and make your super class Turret implement it and make UpgradeTurret() method virtual there.